# What exactly is POM.xml file and What are the uses of it with respect to Spring boot and Maven

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pom.xml

I have just started working with Spring Boot, I want to know what exactly POM file does.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#What_is_the_POM (this link is also visible in the tag wiki of [tag:pom.xml])

Comment: And what is is to Spring boot: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-starters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should start by reading Maven's introduction to POM-files.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html